# PHP conditionally require/use library class

Tags: php, require

I'm using a library to sanitize commands sent to the shell, it is installed with Composer, and included via "use" atatement.

When the script receives a POST, it should require, and then use the library's Command class. However when I put my require and use statement's inside my $_POST check like so:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){

    require 'php-shellcommand/vendor/autoload.php';
    use mikehaertl\shellcommand\Command;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /var/www/html/scrape_nu/index.php on line 9
```

If I pull the two outside the condition, they work perfectly normally...

I have found almost no documentation about the "use" command specifically and I'm not sure if it's included in other, more general info, but php.net/manual doesn't even have an entry for the use command.

I'm wondering if this is a bug, expected behavior, or if there's something else I'm missing. Ideally for performance and security, I'd prefer the library to not even be available unless the $_POST has been set. Are "use" and/or "require" not allowed inside conditionals (and/or other flow control blocks)?

Comment: You do not need to manually require the file. Check composer autoloading PS4

Comment: Hmmm tried deleting - didn't work for me, but not specifically relevant to me at this point...

Comment: see "Scoping rules for importing" topic [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php): "The _use_ keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped."

Comment: Well there it is - that's exactly what I was looking for - you should make this an answer so I can accept it

Comment: You can conditionally require, but not conditionally use. I linked a previous Q&A about this that should cover it.

Comment: @Raheel I think you still have to require the autoload script at some point, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic `vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: Very good - would you consider unlocking so I can answer my own question? I would like to include my modified code - I think other people may be struggling with the ambiguity of this and related issues